# How I can pass list from activity to another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm new to Android Studio and try to develop my first application.

I have 3 activities MainActivity, DashboardActivity, and SplashActivity.

**DashboardActivity -**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    Hooks();
    allQuestionsList=listS;
    Collections.shuffle(allQuestionsList);
    modelClass = listS.get(index);

    setAllData();
```

}

**SplashActivity-**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<ModelClass> listS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity_main);

    listS = new ArrayList<>();
    listS.add(new ModelClass("here is the question", "a", "b", "c", "d", "answer"));
    listS.add(new ModelClass("Under-inflated tires increase fuel consumption. A single tire under-inflated by 56 kpa (8 psi) can increase fuel consumption by?", "25 per cent", "15 per cent", "Seven per cent", "Four per cent", "Four per cent"));
    listS.add(new ModelClass("You are not allowed to park a vehicle within _____________ of a pedestrian corridor", "9 metres", "3 metres", "30 metres", "15 metres", "15 metres"));
    listS.add(new ModelClass("What class licence permits the holder to operate a motorcycle?", "Class 4", "Class 1", "Class 6", "Class 5", "Class 6"));
    listS.add(new ModelClass("Seatbelts must be worn by all drivers and passengers:", "Only when driving in the city", "Only when carrying passengers", "All the time unless exempted by law", "Only when driving on the highway", "All the time unless exempted by law"));

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest-

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
android:icon="@drawable/mainscreenlogo"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.QuizTheoryApplication"
tools:targetApi="31">

<activity
    android:name=".example.QuizTheoryApplication.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".example.QuizTheoryApplication.DashboardActivity"
    android:label="Preferences"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.iphonik.chameleon.AppPreferenceActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".example.QuizTheoryApplication.SplashActivity"
    android:label="Preferences"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.iphonik.chameleon.AppPreferenceActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem is that my Splash Activity doesn't run and of course, the list is always empty. I've tried to add in Dashboard activity but without success -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ @Override public void run() 
{ Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, SplashActivity.class); startActivity(intent); } }, 1500);
```

I'm also tried to use `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", listS);`

and `ArrayList<String> receivedList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list")` 
But without any success. I would be very happy to help on this matter. Thanks

Comment: Consider moving the `listS` lifecycle to either a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+singleton) class or the [application](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%5Bapplication-lifecycle%5D+application+class) class accessible to any activity.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your ModelClass exactly is. But if you can make it Parcelable or Serializable then you can simply use Bundle to send the data (listS) to the new Activity. You should do it like this:

in **SplashActicity**:

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putParcelableArrayList(YOUR_KEY, listS); // or putSerializable instead if ModelClass can implement Serializable
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   }
```

then in **DashboardActivity**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    listS = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(YOUR_KEY); // or getSerializable instead you used putSerializable
}

Hooks();
allQuestionsList=listS;
Collections.shuffle(allQuestionsList);
modelClass = listS.get(index);

setAllData();
```